# A mixer or an audio interface?

Tags: recording, instruments, synthesizer, mixing, ableton-live

So I wanna jam live and record, I first wanted to buy a normal Behringer mixer with a built-in USB but I've been told the recording quality is not that good compared to audio interfaces, so I have two solutions..Idk which is cheaper or which has more pros:

-A Behringer mixer, and a normal audio interface with two inputs.
-Only an audio interface with multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for price as a major factor, I would suggest the audio interface all the way; mixers get far more pricey than audio interfaces as you go up in quality and an interface will give you all you need for home recording as long as you have software on your computer to mix with.

Mixers tend to be more practical live though, as the speed with which you can mix instruments will be a very valuable live asset.

If you plan on producing records or doing lots of live performances in the future, I would suggest getting a mixer earlier on; the audio difference between them and an interface is very small, even indistinguishable to most.

If you're looking for a more budget-friendly recording unit, the interface will give you what you need with more ease and less price than a mixer.

If it's within your capabilities, I would try to use both in person and see what you prefer.

Comment: To the untrained ear the difference is very subtle, but as you gain more experience in using either format the difference becomes more audible; I should have been more specific about that. This is just due to the fact that the mixer does most of the processing within itself and outputs the product of this processing.

Comment: so if I plugged the mixer into the audio interface, it would be better? But do you think a 2 inputs audio interface is enough? Will I face any problem if I recorded each synthesizer separately?

Comment: Plugging a mixer into the interface wouldn't do much; the audio interface wouldn't increase the audio quality - merely sustain it. Two inputs is enough, even one if you're recording solo. There would be no issues with recording each synthesizer seperately, it doesn't adversely effect anything in your recording.

Comment: What do you mean wouldn't do much? I assume there's a difference in quality between recording from the mixer directly to the DAW and then from the mixer through the audio interface and then to the DAW?

Comment: The audio interface at that point would just be another thing for it to go through, the audio interface can't increase the quality of the audio it receives.

Comment: So having an audio interface is pointless if you wanna use a usb built-in mixer, technically recording synthesizers together whether by using the audio interface or not isn't gonna make any difference!